# Some users gaming the edit system by searching for misspelled words

Tags: discussion, etiquette, suggested-edits

I looked at the edit queue and saw the following set of edits all from the same user changing "alot" to "a lot", with no other value-add to the post:

- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/19349
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/19350
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/19351
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/19352
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/19353
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/19354

This is obviously a pedantic edit, one that doesn't add much value; what should we do with these edits? It's a correct edit, but the rule of thumb has been that pedantry should sit aside unless there's enough change to be made so that some other value is realized while that type of edit is being made...

Comment: [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83075/easy-ways-to-find-answers-that-should-be-comments-for-flagging-purposes/83144#83144) might have something to do with it.

Comment: Irritating indeed - maybe it's worth adding a feature that block edits of users whose suggested edits were rejected X times in a row? It will reduce those things drastically.

Comment: Suggestion: Allow N (3?) rejected edits a day like this: When suggesting an edit, decrement the counter. When an edit is accepted, increment the counter. Do nothing for rejected edits. This rate-limits edit suggestions *and* thwarts poor editors.

Comment: I know its annoying.. since I myself suggest edits with my rep. However What I do is keep away from trivial edits since 2K'ers will get to them, but think about the other, more gross, spelling mistakes. Not only does it look annoying but imagine how easy/difficult it would be to search a question title `hlp wth the fb logn`

Comment: Maybe you can notify <2K'ers they should not suggest trivial edits...

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Yet another rule, just because of some random abuse. Is this problem common enough to justify this proposed change?

Comment: @Tsh it's not random, big part of the suggested edits I see are minor. I don't see a lot so can't say its reflects the real situation though. I tend to either reject them or Improve them, making a "real" edit instead. I'm sure there's some query that can help us though?

Comment: This is really the same question as I asked a few days ago: [Should tiny edits be accepted or rejected in review?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82865/should-tiny-edits-be-accepted-or-rejected-in-review)

Comment: See also: [Typo edits in the title: to approve, or not to approve?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96665/typo-edits-in-the-title-to-approve-or-not-to-approve). (Short answer: approve, because they aid in searchability.

Answer (score 25):

Personally, I would have rejected *thelot* of these edits. I hope our 10k users start doing this as well for cases that are clearly not going far enough.

Perhaps if there was only one, I would be fine with it. But there is a clear pattern here that is disrespectful to the 10k users time.

I see you did reject, that is good. If enough people rejected the edits, the user would have been banned from suggested edits for a week.

There is a cost to approving edits, attention is not *free*.

Comment: Unfortunately there are soft touches who think any edit is a good edit

Comment: @random I think we need more edit wars.

Comment: We need to suspend Rich "Obnoxious mini edits" B's account, and give him 5 <1k accounts instead. That'll produce some entertainment

Comment: How are these edits even possible? Doesn't the six-character minimum apply to question titles?

Comment: I think this should be made much more explicit, as a guideline on the review page itself.

Comment: @alex: No! You're wrong! We need more comment wars!

Comment: @sbi: No, edit wars!

Comment: @sbi: War, what is it good for? Absolutely nothin'!

Comment: @mmyers we are a bit more lax with title edits, cause a typo in a title is really annoying

Comment: @mmyers: No, comment wars!

Comment: @waffles, what about http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83441/whats-the-point-of-the-too-few-characters-error-for-edits? Did the limit get triggered because he also changed a character in the body?

Answer (score 9):

If this was a normal edit, I would not be as bothered by it since, it truly is a correction (even though it is ultra-small).  However, since this is a suggested edit and the user is doing it over and over, in my opinion it does warrant a "could you please cut that out" type of note to the user.