# Typo edits in the title: to approve, or not to approve?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

What's the recommended course of action for edits in the edit-queue that are basically corrections of typos *in the question title* (no other substantive change)?

e.g.:

- (1 character) https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/67422
- (1 character) https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/67423
- (1 character) https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/67424
- (1 character) https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/67425

Also, you'll notice these are all from the same user, who appears to be correcting misspellings of "database".

Comment: approve them if they make sense?

Comment: I don't get it; why did "YOU" approve 3 and reject the fourth?

Comment: On June 22nd, this user appears to have hit the rep cap *purely from approved edits*, all of which appear to be more typo fixes in titles. Dang, this guy deserves a medal or something!

Comment: @camccann There is such a medal already. It's called the _Mortarboard_ badge. He'd also have gotten _Strunk & White_, and if he repeats it on two more days, _Copy Editor_ :)

Answer (score 19):

I just noticed these were title changes!

**In titles, I think it is much more important to get key words correct** -- so in the case of title edits, yes, these are OK and I would approve them.

If they were trivial body changes, I would be much less supportive of this, per https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/in-defense-of-editing/

Answer (score 6):

Reject or improve the suggested edit.

It's like putting on sunglasses on a face like a bucket. The rest of the body could do with some minor work and couldn't hurt fixing up the rest of it.

Yes, titles are the first thing you see. But when you're in there and the rest of the post is a mangled mess like running your fingers over the body of the Toxic Avenger, it's a bit of a bait and switch.

It's like something to do with margarine.

Comment: something to do with margarine? hmmm

Comment: Margarine... The horror!

Comment: I can't **believe** it's not a question!