# What are the terms and conditions for editing posts on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, edits

I saw a post edit, where the revision has no major differences except:

- I am -> I'm
- I have -> I've
- but -> But (since 'but' is not at the start of the sentence)

I don't think the above changes made at the revisions are helpful to any of the readers. But still should we go with these kind of revisions? And is there any T&C for Post Edits, where we can see the rules?

Comment: Which was the post? These changes don't seem to be necessary and I'd have rejected them as too minor.

Comment: What does "T & C" stand for?

Comment: Terms & Conditions I assumed @Yannis.

Comment: @Ben Thanks ;) (yes, I was honestly puzzled by this)

Comment: There is no official "terms and conditions" - there is only etiquette. The guidelines for this are all [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts)

Comment: Thank you guys.. here is the revised question which i have referred to.. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12794128/revisions

Comment: @Ben: How are "terms **and** conditions" different from just ordinary "terms"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic guidelines for editing are outlined in the ["Edit questions and answers" privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit), and minor edits are discouraged:

> Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just change a single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.

Although you need 2000 reputation to earn the "Edit questions and answers" privilege, it's guidelines apply for suggested edits as well.

Comment: There appears to be one exception for tiny edits; when a typo hinders the searchability of a question, it is [suggested](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96665/typo-edits-in-the-title-to-approve-or-not-to-approve) that it should be accepted (though this is no guarantee it will).