# An alert to serial minor edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, serial-edits

I have noticed that [this user, Jamie Hutton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1104926/jamie-hutton) is doing a massive set of typo-correction edit suggestions.

This is pushing the review queue right up (over 70 and over 90 at different points today)  and I am not sure this is of much value -- I would much rather see less focused edits that are more substantial.

It just feels like an abuse of the suggested edits system.

What do you think?

Comment: I wonder if they are just trying to "power through" and get their 1K rep for suggested edits...it certainly doesn't look like behavior that should be encouraged.

Comment: That user has been a member for *2 days* and already has an `archaeologist` badge! WTF?!? It took me months to earn `Strunk & White`

Comment: Is there a cap on how many proposed edits such users can do per-day? Since our review votes are capped, I think there should be, if not.

Comment: So you can change one letter in the title, but you have to change 6 letters in the body of a question if you lack edit privileges? Something seems very wrong about that.

Comment: I think correcting misspellings in titles for questions benefits the site as a whole, but maybe the person that discovered it should propose a massive edit here in meta instead of doing it him/herself.

Comment: Still going... suggested edits 1692911 through 1692939 are more of the same.

Comment: And now I'm out of votes. Why on earth am I vote-limited if edit suggestions aren't?

Comment: @Problem Me too, now. *sigh*

Comment: Wow, he actually hit 190 rep solely on *edits*.

Comment: @AndrewBarber See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days

Comment: Closely related: [Some users gaming the edit system by searching for misspelled words](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83557/some-users-gaming-the-edit-system-by-searching-for-misspelled-words)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/987732/sameera-thilakasiri

Comment: @BradGilbert - I actually find most of hist edits to be good ones, definitely more substantial than single word corrections.

Comment: There were quite a few edits just now, that only removed *thanks*.

Comment: @BradGilbert - Those are considered good edits...

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You're not going to like this answer, but I approved every one of his suggested edits (that were in the queue) except four, where someone got to them first and declined them.  On those four, I went ahead and made the requested spelling changes.

How is correcting spelling errors not making the internet better?  Do you really want to have this discussion the next time someone throws a txtspk question at you?

It might interest you to know that the user rep-capped long before he was done making suggestions.  The system works.

Seriously, there are far more serious things users can do to the site than fix a bunch of spelling errors.  The horror.

Comment: I approve this answer. I've been making edit suggestions to correct minor spelling and grammar errors on one of the betas I am in and every one of them got approved by the SE employees.

Comment: But what if someone searches for the same problem using the same misspelling?  They'll be left high and dry; the horror!      ;)

Comment: I agree with Robert here - the user is trying to help. It's not a big deal, and everyone should stop jumping on him for doing something beneficial.

Comment: I can see this on keywords maybe, but on silly words such as "accommodation" which virtually no one would search for anyways, no way. The words he was changing don't really affect the search and are common misspellings that most people wouldn't even notice. I still don't believe most of them constitute a full edit. A good search would still match the rest of the words and just not the misspelled one.

Comment: @animuson Can you tell me exactly how this (correcting misspellings) makes SO *worse*?

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ: It doesn't make it worse, but it is *not substantive* as an edit. Isn't that the reason for rejecting as too minor? The only thing correcting "accommodation" does is fix *one* misspelling on SO.

Comment: @animuson Who said I agree with that definition of "too minor"? It's certainly not doing the site any harm, so what's the problem here?

Comment: It might be too minor if they're changing things that aren't in need of changing, but if he's changing something that's _wrong_ and making it _right_, that's hardly a bad thing.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ: I just said it doesn't do any harm, but it doesn't really do any good either. So we fixed a misspelling that barely anyone notices anyways and probably 50% of people also make.

Comment: @animuson Then let's do them a favor and teach them how to spell words correctly. I stand by my assertion that *any* grammar/spelling corrections are welcome. It makes the site look more professional.

Comment: When I am in "Review mode" and see an edit like this, I typically dive in and clean up the 23 *other* things that should have been fixed.  So, that's 2 edits to the post by 2 new users.  ***The harm is that the post is closer to CW conversion*** -- perhaps undeservedly so.   This is one more reason why I think we need the "Reject and Improve" feature.

Comment: @BrockAdams You can show your support here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83721/do-we-need-a-reject-and-improve-button

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ, thanks. I forgot to link to that post.

Comment: [Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82873/) and [waffles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83559/) have both expressed the opinion that such edits should be rejected.

Comment: I think that if the behavior is toxic to the community of people that regularly make more _substantial_ edits, it should be discouraged. What I don't know how to do is entice people to take more ownership in the posts they edit, so that upon hitting 'save', the post no longer requires editing.

Comment: Robert - this is actually helpful. I was more interested in the discussion and to see what people think. I am somewhat on the fence here - I see the suggested edits as helpful, but was surprised at the scale and wanted to see what the community thought.

Comment: I agree with what @BrockAdams said, and I'll toss in that I sometimes also see high-reputation users editing only the title in a post that is in **dire** need of major cleanup.

Comment: @jwiscarson: A lot of the comments here seem to suggest that, if a post is to be edited, the editor must take responsibility for cleanup of the entire post. I'm not sure that's fair.  There are plenty of other able-bodied people that can pitch in.

Comment: I see that point -- I would be less concerned about multiple edits if I knew whether or not piecemeal editing pushed questions into CW in rare circumstances. Secondly, I don't know if it's fair to draw a distinction between low-rep users who are suggesting minor corrections and high-rep users who are directly editing. However, my point is: if you're going to target minor suggested edits by new users, maybe it's worth expanding that to high-rep users who have similar editing habits.

Comment: @jwiscarson: If fairness requires that high-rep users be stripped of their ability to make one letter edits that improve a post, I would rather just abandon the prohibition for everyone. High-rep users are given that ability precisely because they have demonstrated that they can be trusted not to abuse it.

Comment: Hm, okay. I buy that distinction completely. Thanks for taking the time to explain your perspective.

Comment: A thousand times yes.

Comment: These kinds of edits improve the posts (albeit mildly in many cases).  The problem is the rate of changes; flooding the front page with a bunch of these at once pushes other questions off before they've had a chance to be seen.  If you're going to do (or approve) these kinds of edits, try to keep the batch sizes reasonable.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with Robert. You can argue too minor if he fixes one typo and you see 6 others, or he fixes one indent and you see six others... but even then its grey.. If something is wrong we are all better served by it being correct.  Isn't the goal of this to provide the best reference material and self-directed content?

The Linux Principle: With enough eyes, all problems are trivial.

Comment: Although I agree with this post, I am concerned that this will provoke the creation of "edit bots" that watch every new answer and check for spelling errors, and if there are enough corrections, it will suggest the edit, filling the queue with spelling edits.

Answer (score 10):

Cleaning up spelling errors in question titles has some small benefit ε which is—taken alone—greater than 0. Seems the problem is really how it interacts with other site features:

- The edit queue must be reviewed by high-rep users, at a cost greater than ε
- Doesn't this bump questions as well? This cost may or may not be greater than ε, no idea. SO gets so many questions that a bump doesn't last long.

Seems like the real problem is the edit queue—fix it. If SO Dev added a rule:

- If a title edit is only a few characters, **AND**
- those characters are part of a word not in *some dictionary*, **AND**
- the new word *is* in *some dictionary*
- **THEN** auto-approve

That seems fairly low-risk, and would get rid of most all of the costs of these tiny edits.

Answer (score 4):

This guy has done a search for the words "framwork" and "expresion" in titles of posts and is now on a crusade to correct them all. Either he is an English major with a concentration in Spelling, or he is trying to crank up his rep +2 at a time, or he is on a crusade for the Copy Editor badge. In any case, he must be stopped!

He has a total of 10 points from answers, none from questions. All of his rep (238 last time I looked) is from edits.

Please, someone stop him! I've already reached my 40 reject limit on suggested edit for today, and he's still going strong!

Comment: I think framwork is an excellent thing to correct. I guess there are quite a few people that would search for framework.

Comment: +1 for writing an epic answer.

Comment: He helps people searching for "framework" or "expression" finding more answers. Why is that bad?

Comment: Why on Earth were you rejecting good edits?

Comment: I somehow keep ending up reading this page again and again each time I find a user with hundreds of rep points gained by editing lower case "I"s and uncapitalized first words.

Comment: Searching for "framework" is the same as searching for "framwork". Any decent search engine won't mind.