# Please stop the spell-check police!

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, moderation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An alert to serial minor edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116509/an-alert-to-serial-minor-edits)

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1104926/jamie-hutton) is going through every single post that has ever misspelled "framework" or "expression" to edit the titles. Many of these posts are over a year old with an accepted answer and no recent activity apart from his edits. Is this really a useful thing to be doing? From my perspective, it's cluttering up the suggested edits with a bunch of nonsense.

Also, it's pretty clear that he did a search for all posts with "Framwork" in the title so that he could change the titles to "Framework". He has over 50 edits that I've seen so far that are exactly this, all within the past few hours.

Comment: Yup; We've been seeing him today: [Serial Minor Edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116509/an-alert-to-serial-minor-edits)

Comment: +1 Fully supportive of more attention for this incident, but this does dupe the earlier post.