# Should this minor title edit have been approved or rejected?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I've read several of the questions here relating to how to deal with minor edits.  However, for [this particular suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3472996), even though it's as minor as it can get, I was tempted to accept it.

My reasoning is that, as this affects the title of the page itself, this could be accepted to improve SEO for this particular question.  In my mind, questions only have value if they can be found.  Having said that, in this case (i.e. `serve` vs `server`) it means very little, and I'd be surprised if a modern-day search engine would distinguish between the two.

Now that it's been approved anyway, was it the right thing to do?  I ask as I've seen a few suggested edits like this now and I've been skipping them because I've not been sure.

Comment: I would have rejected it if the edit failed to fix other mistakes in the post. However, given that the question was otherwise fine, I would have accepted it. See **[this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116555/232567)**

Comment: @JoshC That makes sense, thanks.  Thanks for the edit, too.

Comment: For edits on recent items, I see no reason not to ask the author to fix it up themselves. Comment to the author, delete the comment when actioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aha - I found something to nitpick in the edit!

> So far, al seems good

That is enough to make the edit "too minor", since it didn't catch that glaring mistake.

...

Okay, I admit I didn't notice it on the first pass through.  But it's always a good idea to be extremely vigilant on minor edits like this.  Make sure that **nothing else** in the post needs to be corrected.

In this case, instead of approving, I would have elected to *improve*, and at least let Chrome's spellchecker hit it, to see what stood out.

Comment: Thanks, Makoto.  So the bottom line is: accept if the edit addresses everything that needs to be fixed (or perhaps, there's nothing left to fix).

Comment: And 'thanks` too. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20184702/revisions