# Edits to tags and titles get stuck on the 'at least 6 chars' blocker when accompanied by minor body edits

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I've been trying to edit the tags and title of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18634/), to improve its focus on the actual problem encountered by the post author.

During the edit, I thought of a little formatting improvement that could be performed in the question body. Since the change was already meaningful, and because it would have been accepted as it was, I thought it would also be possible to correct the formatting a little bit. Turns out I couldn't. The edit got stuck on the "at least 6 chars non whitespace characters" blocker.

Is there simple way to forget about changes to the post body so that the original edit can get accepted?

Wouldn't the sites be even better if they allowed small body edits when the title and/or tags are being modified?

Comment: While there is the occasional near-perfect post where you want to fix a single character in a code example, this wasn't one. For example you could have added words like “hyphen” and “dash” as search fodder. I didn't bother because it was a duplicate, but I'm going to go improve the earlier question which I now see lacks this search fodder.

Comment: I'll think about it next time!

Answer (score 1):

Suggested edits must be substantive, as they have to be approved by other users and thus take time and effort from your peers.

If you wish to make trivial, bit-twiddling changes to posts you must earn 2k reputation.

Comment: I don't understand. Title edit is substantive enough. Tag edit is substantive enough. But Title+Tag+Body edit is not?

Comment: true, but this would be a backdoor to make trivial body edits -- simply make trivial title changes along with it. Bottom line, if you are going to touch the body, it must be a substantive change to the body.

Comment: Again, I was editing title + tags + body, but I couldn't find something else to change in the body, except for the removal of two capitals letters. So, I'm starting to use [stupidish workarounds](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/revisions/ae3015ad-5660-4cba-b8c2-d6f8c38fa332/view-source) to bypass stupidish rules :-/ And, no it's not that easy to quickly obtain 2k on a beta.