# Title edits don't count towards minimum-character edit limit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Title edit plus minor body edit return ‘too short’ error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79342/title-edit-plus-minor-body-edit-return-too-short-error)

I've just come across a question that had fine content, but an appalling title, so I attempted to turn the title into something usable. Now my edits need to be modified—fair enough—but it seems my changes to the title didn't count towards the minimum character limit.

Seems to me that I shouldn't have to make bogus edits to a question's content to have my relatively substantial edits to the title change; certainly there was more than a 6-character change to the title.

Comment: I see you eventually [found what to edit](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/140257) in the body? :)

Comment: Funny, I edited only the title of this question and it let me. :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79342/title-edit-plus-minor-body-edit-return-too-short-error Strangely enough there is an answer which says this has been fixed :-)

Answer (score 1):

When suggesting an edit, you must edit at least 6 characters in the body - these are the rules, to change them you can ask for "feature request" but I doubt it will get changed.

In 99% of the cases, there are always minor things to edit in the body (e.g. `i` to `I` etc) and if you truly don't see anything need editing in the body, just add this:

```
<!-- break -->
```

It will not cause any visible change and let you edit the title.

Comment: Avoiding the 6-character limit is not what I would suggest to users who don't have the privilege of editing any post. It would allow a "too minor" edit to pass, which would then be rejected from another user who took his time to review.

Comment: @kiamlaluno in my opinion title is vital - having correct titles is very important, so I tend to approve "title only" edits. I don't expect everyone to share my opinion though and of course if I see the post need more editing, I click the Improve and do it myself.

Comment: There are many users who can edit a title; there is no need to teach somebody a trick that should be used with judgement.